# How can I work with SQL NULL values and JSON in a good way?

Tags: sql, json, go

Go types like `Int64` and `String` cannot store null values,
so I found I could use [sql.NullInt64](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64) and [sql.NullString](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString) for this.

But when I use these in a Struct,
and generate JSON from the Struct with the [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package,
then the format is different to when I use regular `Int64` and `String` types.

The JSON has an additional level because the sql.Null*** is also a Struct.

Is there a good workaround for this,
or should I not use NULLs in my SQL database?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "not how it used to be when I used regular int64 and string" in your question.

Comment: you have tried using pointers to ints, yes?  ie: var anint *int, then using &anint  if its null the pointer will be nil.  works fine with JSON encoding.  this works with gorp for sure, haven't tested with straight sql package though

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Types like `sql.NullInt64` do not implement any special handling for JSON marshaling or unmarshaling, so the default rules apply.  Since the type is a struct, it gets marshalled as an object with its fields as attributes.

One way to work around this is to create your own type that implements the `json.Marshaller` / `json.Unmarshaler` interfaces.  By embedding the `sql.NullInt64` type, we get the SQL methods for free.  Something like this:

```
type JsonNullInt64 struct {
    sql.NullInt64
}

func (v JsonNullInt64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(v.Int64)
    } else {
        return json.Marshal(nil)
    }
}

func (v *JsonNullInt64) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Unmarshalling into a pointer will let us detect null
    var x *int64
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &x); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if x != nil {
        v.Valid = true
        v.Int64 = *x
    } else {
        v.Valid = false
    }
    return nil
}
```

If you use this type in place of `sql.NullInt64`, it should be encoded as you expect.

You can test this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/zFESxLcd-c

Comment: What a great solution! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it's redundant to say, but so fantastic to have Golang Playgrounds to demonstrate stuff like this - really makes a huge difference for language adoption.  Thanks for a great answer.

Comment: Thanks mate! This is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 46):

If you use the [null.v3](https://gopkg.in/guregu/null.v3) package, you won't need to implement any of the marshal or unmarshal methods. It's a superset of the sql.Null structs and is probably what you want.

```
package main

import "gopkg.in/guregu/null.v3"

type Person struct {
    Name     string      `json:"id"`
    Age      int         `json:"age"`
    NickName null.String `json:"nickname"` // Optional
}
```

If you'd like to see a full Golang webserver that uses sqlite, nulls, and json you can consult [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stephen-mw/f55cb15f1d097f0fc3a81221a5835804).

Comment: This is a massive time-saver. I thought I was going to have to write all of the marshaling code but this package works perfectly.