# Jmoiron SQLX Golang common interface

Tags: go, sqlx

I am new to golang and using Jmoiron Sqlx package for querying the Postgres Database(select query) . The waY I am doing is creating a sql string and calling Select(dest interface{}, query string,args) method. While it works well , the problem is I am generating my sql String dynamically and as such the destination structure should be different for each response .

For ex : - One query can be

```
Select a,b,c,d from table A ;
```

the other can be

```
Select x,y,z from Table B;
```

From what i understand , there should be two different structs defined for Select Method to work i.e.

```
Struct Resp1{
   a string
   b string
   c  string
   d string
}
```

And,

```
Struct Resp2{
   x string
   y string
   z  string

}
```

And then invoke select as `db.Select(&resp1,query,args)` and `db.Select(&resp2,query,args)`
I am thinking if its possible for me to define a common Struct

```
say Resp3{
   a string
   b string
   c  string
   d string
   x string
   y string
   z  string
}
```

And based on my select query populates only the matching columns (i.e only a,b,c,d for first and x,y,z for second) .

I tried searching but couldnt get any leads .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get answer to this here and since I needed this , I dug up myself and I found how to solve this in an efficient way .

To solve this one can define all your String values as sql.NullString , integer as sql.int64 , float as sql.float64 etc .

So Say your table is having columns a,b,c,d,e,f and for some response you only have to display a,b,d for some other d,e and so on . Instead of creating different structures and mapping them in db.Select(...) statement Just define ur struct as follows

```
a       sql.NullString `json:"whatever u wish to have as key,omitempty"`
b       sql.NullString `json:"b,omitempty"`
c       sql.NullString `json:"c,omitempty"`
d       sql.int64  `json:"d,omitempty"`
e       sql.float64  `json:"e,omitempty"`
```

Remember sql.NullString will be Marshalled  to json with an additional key displayed (Valid:boolean) . You can follow approach here to fix that  [How can I work with sql NULL values and JSON in Golang in a good way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072172/how-can-i-work-with-sql-null-values-and-json-in-golang-in-a-good-way)

Hope this is helpful to someone.!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually your struct should represent all fields of SQL table, not only fields that you are fetching in `SELECT`, so you can just do `SELECT * FROM...` and deserialize response from db to your struct `Resp3`.

Comment: Select * is a dangerous ploy to play with (In case you add or remove columns) . It may be ok with goLang but with generic use in ORM world (select *) should be avoided .