# Invalid field found for struct when using custom json marshaller

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm using Gorm with `sql.NullString` for few fields. I'm also converting that struct to json and storing it in a different Cassandra table as string. In the Cassandra table I see `"modifiedBy":{"String":"","Valid":false}` but I want to store only value. So I added my own json marshaller:

```
type NullString sql.NullString

func (x *NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !x.Valid {
        n, _ := json.Marshal(nil)
        return n, nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(x.String)
}
```

so that it returns `nil` or a string value only. But when trying to insert in the MySQL table using Gorm, I get:

`invalid field found for struct  fpl/models.User's field Modified_By, need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface`.

Declaring the struct:

```
{
 ...
  Modified_By NullString `json:"modifiedBy" gorm:"column:modified_by;DEFAULT:null"`
}
```

I'm storing the json in Cassandra table and the actual data in struct in MySQL. To avoid storing `"modifiedBy":{"String":"","Valid":false}` and store only the string value, I used the custom marshal json, but I'm not able to insert into MySQL. How do I make this work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I work with SQL NULL values and JSON in a good way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072172/how-can-i-work-with-sql-null-values-and-json-in-a-good-way)

Comment: @Peter no it does not. I have already done what is said there. that is not the problem

Comment: Your question doesn't show any attempt of embedding the NullString type (note that this is different from defining a new type that has NullString as the underlying type, as shown in the question). If embedding didn't work for you update the question to include this code as well.