# Inserting `sql.Nulltime` into Postgres `timestamp with time zone`

Tags: database, postgresql, go

Let's s say I have struct with a field like:

```
FinishedAt   sql.NullTime `json:"finished_at"`
```

```
var out models.Job
err := client.QueryRow(ctx, updateQuery,
    &job.FinishedAt,
).Scan(
    &out.FinishedAt,
)
```

Above I use `"github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"` to work with PG.

There is no error during the update but the field is set to `null` after the request.

Using `&job.FinishedAt.Time` as an argument works appropriately but I want to understand why the `sql.Nulltime` type doesn't work.

Is that just related to how the library works?

Comment: Is `job.FinishedAt` valid? What is its `job.FinishedAt.Valid` value?

Comment: This is the value it receives:
`FinishedAt:   sql.NullTime{Time: now}`

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that the `Valid` value is false for some reason

Comment: So `Valid` is `false` and therefore the `Value() (driver.Value, error)` will return `NULL`.

Comment: *"for some reason"* -- `false` is the *zero* value of the `bool` type, i.e. any bool value not explicitly initialized will be implicitly initialized to `false`. https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value

Comment: That makes sense. Well, in such a case it's a bit clumsy because converting a `time.Time instance to `sql.NullTime` requires setting both fields of the struct. But at least that is correct :)

Comment: You could also just use a pointer instead of `sql.NullTime`. i.e. `FinishedAt  *time.Time \`json:"finished_at"\``. Then if the field is `nil` it will be stored as `NULL`, if it's not `nil` then the `time.Time`'s value will be stored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I work with SQL NULL values and JSON in a good way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072172/how-can-i-work-with-sql-null-values-and-json-in-a-good-way)